# How to make a color white using filter property in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-filters

I have a `svg` image where I want to change the color of the `svg` using the css `filter` property.

```css
body {
  background-color: #dadada;
}

.custom-1 {
  filter: invert(0.5);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/62/62945.svg" class="standard" width="50" height="50" alt="img">

<img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/62/62945.svg" class="custom-1" width="50" height="50" alt="img">
```

How can I make the `svg` image as white color.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can combine filter properties like this.

```
brightness(0) invert(1);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #dadada;
}

.custom-1 {
  filter: invert(0.5);
}

.custom-2 {
  filter:  brightness(0) invert(1);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg" class="standard" width="50" height="50" alt="img">

<img src="https://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg" class="custom-1" width="50" height="50" alt="img">

<img src="https://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg" class="custom-2" width="50" height="50" alt="img">
```

**EDIT** - *25th May 2021*:

This answer has been quite popular, thus I want to warn you that `filter` is **not** supported by [Internet Explorer and Opera Mini](https://caniuse.com/?search=filter). The good news is that [Microsoft is slowly phasing out IE](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-blog/microsoft-365-apps-say-farewell-to-internet-explorer-11-and/ba-p/1591666).

Take care!

Comment: Oh yeah, you make the brightness as 0 which goes to black then invert the color. Thank for the answer.

Comment: Exactly! @Rehan